# Probability distribution function EX^2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X > 0$ with density $f(x)$ and distribution function $F(x)$. Show that $E(X^2) = 2\int_0^\infty x(1−F(x))dx$.

I have no clue where to even start with this question.

Comment: By $Z$ you mean $\int$? And by $E(X)^2$ you mean $E(X^2)$?  If so, use integration by parts.

Comment: Hi fjl123, if you want to get good answers to your questions it is very useful to format your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This will increase the readability of your questions and lead to more high-quality answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the expectation can be written as follow. For a non-negative random variable $X$,
$$ \mathbf{E}X = \int_0^\infty \textbf{P}(X > t) dt.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}X^2 &= \int_0^\infty \textbf{P}(X^2 > t) dt= \int_0^\infty \textbf{P}(X >\sqrt{t}) dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \textbf{P}(X > x) (2x)dx = 2\int_0^\infty x\textbf{P}(X > x) dx
\end{align}
where $\sqrt{t} = x$ and $dt = 2xdx$ is ued in the third equality.